# Nginx: счет загрузок файлов

Tags: nginx

Я хочу считать количество загрзок какого-то файла в бэкэнде. Для этого я предполагаю настроить nginx так, чтобы после загрузки файла клиентом он делал запрос на `http://127.0.0.1/count?path=...`

В конфиг-файле содержится:

```
location /downloads/fs {
    alias /var/app/downloads/fs;
    post_action @count;
}

location @count {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/count?path=$uri;
    #internal;
}
```

Лог nginx содержит такое:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017:09:14:08 +0700] "GET /count?path=/downloads/fs/file.txt HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
192.168.1.181 - - [27/Jun/2017:09:14:08 +0700] "GET /downloads/fs/file.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 197017892 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
```

errors.log пуст. В логе моего бэкэнда отсутствует отметка о запросе к `/count`. Если же я в браузере сам сделаю запрос к `/count` такой, как записан в логе nginx, то бэкенд срабатывает правильно.

Т.о., по какой-то причине в действительности не происходит запроса в post_action. В чем причина? Как необходимо настроить nginx?

**UPD:**
Есть еще такой локейшн:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://serv;
}
```

`serv` здесь - это:

```
upstream serv {
    server unix:///tmp/serv.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Бэкенд написан на Django

Comment: Гадание по коду 301: бэкенд отдаёт редирект с HTTP на HTTPS?

Comment: @andreymal Эмм, нет, думаю дело еще в одном локейшене. Дополнил в вопросе. Правильно ли я понимаю, что nginx сам делает запрос в post_action, но не редиректит его так, как я ожидаю?